# Example to control relay module

Tags: android, relay

Does anyone know how to program a device on the android to control this relay module. I do not know about it and I did found a program but only on windows :( ?

I want to connect this relay to the melex (golf cart). The android app is supposed to cut off the ignition. And I do not know how to program it

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zT1F.jpg)

Comment: please consider adding more detail to your question as this one is unanswerable

Comment: @SebastianSchneider I added additional description